# Show "About Phone" in android settings through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to show the "About Phone" Section of android Settings app on click of a button in my app. I could not find an Intent for this from the [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) Reference page, although there are intents for others like wifi bluetooth etc.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use this intent your *minimum sdk level* should be **8** and to add a try `ActivityNotFoundException` since this intent may not exist.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(i);
```

> public static final String ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS
>
> Added in API level 8 Activity Action: Show general device information
>   settings (serial number, software version, phone number, etc.).
>
> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.

Comment: I have tried ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS . but it shows the entire settings itself. Seems like a bug.

Comment: As per the docs it should display the device information if it exists. You can try this in another phone.